# concatenate CheckBox control name with string

Tags: vb.net, webforms

Have a bunch of checkboxes on a win form.
I want to be able to iterate through them looking to see if they are checked or not.  I do know how to find the controls on a form.

My checkboxes are named "CBr3C1"  through "CBr12C1" where "r" stands for row number on the form. SO I want to iterate through rows 3 to 12.  I understand the at control names are of a control type.

If I set up a loop like for Z as integer = 1 to 12
Can I and How do I convert "CBrZC1" into a control name.

```
  Dim Z As Integer = 3

    For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Form.Controls

        If TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox Then
            ctlNameis = CType(ctrl, CheckBox).ID

            If Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(ctlNameis, 3) = ("CBr") Then
                If Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(ctlNameis, 2) = ("C" & PltLabelNbr) Then


                    If Me.CBrZC1.Checked = True Then

                        '****   dosomething

                    Else
                    End If
                    Z += 1
                    If Z = 13 Then
                        Exit Sub

                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

I have left my original answer for completeness but, as this is for Web Forms, it's not actually applicable. I don't use Web Forms so I'm not sure whether there's a better way but this bit of LINQ should do the trick:

```vb
For r = 3 To 12
    Dim cbx = Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)().First(Function(cb) cb.ID = $"CBr{r}C1")

    If cbx.Checked Then
        '...
    End If
Next
```

It uses the same basic structure as the original code but avoids indexing the `Controls` collection. `OfType` will filter out anything that isn't a `CheckBox` and also handle casting, then `First` will get the first item with the specified `ID`.

ORIGINAL:

Given that you know exactly what the names are, there's no need to look at every control. Just get the control with the name you want, e.g.

```vb
For r = 3 To 12
    Dim cbx = DirectCast(Controls($"CBr{r}C1"), CheckBox)

    If cbx.Checked Then
        '...
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.   It throws an error when I run the code you presented. The error states "System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "CBr3C1" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'"

Comment: @dashley, have you declared your own variable/property named `Controls`? As per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.item?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), you can index the `Control.Controls` property by ordinal or name. The code I posted should work on that basis, unless `Controls` refers to something else, e.g. an array variable, in your specific project. Note that the code I posted was intended to be used within a form, so `Controls` would refer to that form's `Controls` property. Adjust as needed.

Comment: I Guess I'm experiencing a conflict somewhere. I've created a separate form and re-tested the code you posted and it works perfectly.  I'll chase down the conflict and re-work my code. Thanks again  :)

Comment: Should have mentioned I'm on a Webform as opposed to a window form.  I tested the code by itself on a webform at work and when I got home I started running into the error 'Conversion from string "CBr3C1" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'"   
I'm missing something here.    Not fully understanding your input on Controls declaration

Comment: @dashley, yes, you should have mentioned that it was Web Forms. You should always add a tag for the technology being used. That said, I probably should have asked rather than assuming WinForms. I probably should have been able to tell from the use of `Me.Form` and `.ID`.

Comment: @dashley, I have updated my answer with a solution that should work for Web Forms.

Comment: Thank you again for responding. I don't do LINQ and it was throwing a different error(System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no matching element'  ). I'm going to use your original answer and have dumped the webform project and created a Windows Form Project and it's working fine. Actually the re-write using you code is more streamlined and I'm liking it.  I really do appreciate you taking the time to respond. It has helped immensely , Thanks Again